# Exact Subfigure sizing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm plotting some indices data on A4 paper with 6 images in 3x2 row-cols.  I've got the basic code working and it plots this dataframe data into the following 6 plots.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D1Q1.jpg

```
def plot_idx(df,image,key):
    # reset the default parameters
    plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 8.
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.267, 11.692) #aA paper
    fig = plt.figure()
    #plot all the 6 figures and save the 3x2 image as png

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(321) # first row first image
    #compute all time 
    alltime = df['Close'].count()
    x,y,x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = min_max(df,alltime)
    ax1.plot(x, y,'r')
    ax1.plot(x_min,y_min,'o')
    ax1.plot(x_max,y_max,'o')
    ax1.set_xlabel('year')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Index Close')
    ax1.set_title(plot_title[-1])
    ax1.fill_between(x,y,facecolor='red')
    ax1.annotate(y_min, xy=(x_min,y_min), xytext=(x_min,y_min +250))
    ax1.annotate(y_max, xy=(x_max,y_max), xytext=(x_max,y_max +250))

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(322) # first row second image
    # compute ytd 
    ytd = df.ix[baseline_year:]['Close'].count()
    x,y,x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = min_max(df,ytd)
    ax2.plot(x, y,'r')
    ....
    # repeat 4 more times for other figs

    fig.suptitle(key, fontsize=10)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(image)
```

How do I get the subplots into A4/6 equal sized plots with a little bit of space on top for the title?  as in 8.267/2 x 11.69/3 size?  The tight_layout helps but I'd like more control over the sizes and placement.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control, you can use `fig.add_axes` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, .4, .4,])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.1, .5, .4, .4,])
# ... and so one for as many figures as you want
# or wrap it all up in a loop
```

The down side is this gets really annoying do write/maintain, as you have to make sure the ticks and axes labels don't overlap with each other.

There is also [`GridSpec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) which gives you more control over spanning columns and such.

Comment: what do the values of the rect mean in the context of a subplot? I can see the l,b,w,h part but what does left, bottom mean here?

Comment: The `left` and `bottom` are the location of the bottom left corner of the axes in figure fraction units.